How to join a table with 2 other tables with 2 where clauses for each other table?
I have this data:
CUST_ORDER_LINE, primary keys Cust_order_id and Line_no



CUST_ORDER_ID
LINE_NO
PART_ID
QTY




S97856
1
1221
5


S98854
1
2331
5



WORK_ORDER, primary keys are Base_id, Lot_id, Sub_id, and split_id



BASE_ID
LOT_ID
SUB_ID
SPLIT_ID
USER_DEF1
QTY
STATUS




WW246731
1
0
0
EVAL
5
RELEASED


WW245520
1
0
0
QUAL
5
RELEASED



DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK (only foreign keys)



DEMAND_TYPE
DEMAND_BASE_ID
DEMAND_LOT_ID
DEMAND_SUB_ID
DEMAND_SPLIT_ID
DEMAND_SEQ_NO
SUPPLY_TYPE
SUPPLY_BASE_ID
SUPPLY_LOT_ID
SUPPLY_SUB_ID
SUPPLY_SPLIT_ID
SUPPLY_SEQ_NO




CO
S97856
NULL
NULL
NULL
1
WO
WW246731
1
0
0
NULL


CO
S98854
NULL
NULL
NULL
1
WO
WW245520
1
0
0
NULL


WO
WW245520
1
0
0
NULL
PO
P525552
NULL
NULL
NULL
0



I'd like to get this result:



CUST_ORDER_ID
LINE_NO
PART_ID
QTY
WORK ORDER
STATUS
USER1




S97856
1
1221
5
WW246731
RELEASED
EVAL


S97856
1
2331
5
WW245520
RELEASED
QUAL



Demand_supply_link  holds the link between cust_order_line and work_order; there is no direct link between those tables. So there are 3 tables we are trying to join, but we are not able to get the work_order table to join correctly.
Ideally the links should be as follows in the join statement.  As mentioned when trying to join the work order table the database doesn't recognize the wo.BASE_ID pull for example.
FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE col
JOIN DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK dsl ON
    dsl.DEMAND_BASE_ID = col.CUST_ORDER_ID
    AND dsl.DEMAND_SEQ_NO = col.LINE_NO
    AND dsl.DEMAND_TYPE = 'CO' 
    -- (This tells the DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK table to ignore DEMAND types where the demand is a WO (workorder), and that it should be Customer Orders CO)

JOIN WORK_ORDER wo ON
    dsl.SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO'
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_BASE_ID = wo.BASE_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_LOT_ID = wo.LOT_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_SPLIT_ID = wo.SPLIT_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_SUB_ID = wo.SUB_ID

We tried various forms of nesting the joins, but we are probably doing it incorrectly. When attempting the above join, the query will not run. SQL says that all of the work_order column names are invalid.  See below screenshot starting where wo.BASE_ID and below in the code are not recognized.


Please update your question with sample data for your source tables, the result you are trying to achieve and the result you are currently getting. Can you also explain what the issue is - just stating that something “isn’t working” with no other information doesn’t really help - in what way is it not working?

just because SSMS doesn't recognize those columns, doesn't mean they don't exist, the "unintellisense" is sometimes slow to refresh

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

what does: select * from VMFG9.sys.columns where name = 'BASE_ID' and object_id = object_id('VMFG9.dbo.WORK_ORDER') returns

It could be something with case sensitivity. What does: select * from VMFG9.sys.columns where UPPER(name) = 'BASE_ID' and object_id = object_id('VMFG9.dbo.WORK_ORDER') returns, it is same as above?

select
        col.cust_order_id,
        col.line_no,
        col.part_id,
        col.qty,
        wo.base_id WorkOrder,
        wo.status
    from
        cust_order_line col
    JOIN demand_supply_link dsl
        on col.cust_order_id = dsl.demand_base_id
        and col.line_no = dsl.demand_seq_no
        and dsl.demand_type = 'CO'
    JOIN work_order wo
        on dsl.supply_base_id = wo.base_id
        AND dsl.SUPPLY_LOT_ID = wo.LOT_ID
        AND dsl.SUPPLY_SPLIT_ID = wo.SPLIT_ID 
        AND dsl.SUPPLY_SUB_ID = wo.SUB_ID
        AND dsl.SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' 

But I have no idea where your user column is coming from.

If the column names really are correct, this should be the correct code:
SELECT col.CUST_ORDER_ID, col.LINE_NO, col.PART_ID
    , wo.QTY, wo.BASE_ID As [WORK ORDER], wo.STATUS, wo.USER_DEF1 USER1
FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE col
INNER JOIN DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK dsl ON dsl.DEMAND_TYPE = 'CO'
    AND dsl.DEMAND_BASE_ID = col.CUST_ORDER_ID 
    AND dsl.DEMAND_SEQ_NO = col.LINE_NO
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_TYPE = 'WO' -- Moved this expression
INNER JOIN WORK_ORDER wo ON
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_BASE_ID = wo.BASE_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_LOT_ID = wo.LOT_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_SPLIT_ID = wo.SPLIT_ID
    AND dsl.SUPPLY_SUB_ID = wo.SUB_ID

Otherwise, make sure you're really looking at the table you think you are.

The column names are correct, and we tried your solution, but we still get a syntax error and SQL says wo.BASE_ID is an invalid column name.

Just close & reopen the SSMS application,It should resolve the problem..
